# Approximate the unit ball in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, by compact sets?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, convex-analysis, compactness, game-theory

Are there some common ways to approximate the unit ball in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, by compact sets? (note that the unit ball isn't compact.)

My goal is to prove a statement which holds for a compact set, also holds on the unit ball. The proof for a compact set makes use of the definition of compactness (i.e. an open cover contains a finite open cover).

I also wonder what are some general approaches for proving such generalization?

Thanks.

---

My specific problem is to show that:

given a function $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb R$, 
if we can show that

> when $X$ is convex and **compact**, and $Y$ convex,
>   and $f$ is bounded, convex and **continuous** in the first argument, and concave in the first argument,
>   $$\inf_{x \in X} \sup_{y \in Y} f(x,y) \leq \sup_{y \in Y} \inf_{x \in X} f(x,y).$$

then 
we can also show that

> When $X$ and $Y$ are **unit balls in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space**, 
>   and 
>   $f$ is convex and **1-Lipschitz** in the first argument,
>   and  concave in the second argument,
>   $$\inf_{x \in X} \sup_{y \in Y} f(x,y) \leq \sup_{y \in Y} \inf_{x \in X} f(x,y).$$

Comment: One common way to deal with Hilbert space ... first prove your result in finite-dimensional space, in such a way that you can take a limit to get the Hilbert-space result.

Comment: perhaps if compactness in the weak topology is enough ...

Comment: You can always take compact operators $K_n$ that converge strongly to $1$ and take $K_n$-images of the unit ball.

Comment: @AlexanderShamov: Are there some examples for proving such generalization in your way?

Comment: @GEdgar: Are there some examples for proving such generalization in your way?

Comment: @user8268:Are there some examples for proving such generalization in your way?

Comment: Example: prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  Prove the finite-dimensional case, then take a limit.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thanks. Do you have some link/reference for me to read in detail?

Comment: I believe that the question you are asking is too broad and vague to be meaningful. Could you be more specific about the kind of results you are interested in?

Comment: @AlexanderShamov: I updated my post with my specific question.

Comment: @GEdgar: I updated my post with my specific question.